# (Hitbox) OnTriggerEnter2D only work if enemy is moving

Tags: unity, 2d, collision-detection

(UPTADE) I am developing a 2D Topdown Rpg Game. I have a problem with trigger colliders. I have button which make active an object and ı use it like Hitbox when i press button ı destroy enemy if it is touching hitbox but there is a problem about something. When i press button enemy is destroyed if only enemy is moving when it stop i cant destroy it

How can I fix this?

This is my hitbox's destroy script

````
 private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {

        if (other.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }
    }
```
````

Comment: Can you describe what specific symptoms you mean by "not work" and "work"?

Comment: I tried to fix the grammar in your post. But for some cases I had to guess a bit because I wasn't really sure what you meant. Can you please read my edit and tell me if I understood everything correctly?

Comment: I have Hitboxes for 4 way left right up and down. Normally when i press attack i destroy enemy but İf enemy touches my Players collider . My hitbox cant destroy enemy Sorry about my English

Comment: Sounds like you should show us your attack code and the configuration of these objects in your scene/inspector.

Comment: how can i send video? I have 2 short video. It explain what my problem is.

Comment: You cannot send video on this site. You can upload the video to a site like YouTube then add a link to it in your question. But I'd say it's even better to describe your setup step by step with text and images, so the question does not rely on an external link to be understood.

Comment: I found the Solution. I add moving animation for colliderbox then it worked

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, not as a comment. Be sure to include enough detail that a stranger reading your post a year from now would be able to understand and apply your method to solve a similar problem in their own game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. If anyone come across with same problem just add animation to collider because if you dont do that your collider wont be triggered